# What is the algorithm to read fusemap from PAL IC?

Tags: programmable-logic

I am aware that it's not always possible due to security fuse, but I would like to at least try to read the fusemap from a certain PAL16R6 chip. I would like to do it using MCU like Arduino, not a dedicated expensive programmer. Problem is, that I can't find any info regarding programming/verifying algorithm for PAL's.

The TI datasheet for PAL16R6 contains only this short information: *"Complete programming specifications, algorithms, and the latest information on hardware, software, and
firmware are available upon request"*, and that's all. So, is there any document/open source software/anything which I could examine to find some information regarding procedure of programming and reading back PAL fusemaps?

Comment: Have you tried asking TI for the specifications?

Comment: There is a [thread on the official TI support forum](https://e2e.ti.com/support/logic-group/logic/f/logic-forum/1279055/pal16r4a-2m-programming-tool-enquiry/4850802#4850802) with information about these PAL devices. Maybe it contains what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://www.techtravels.org/reverse-engineering-pals/) offers some useful information?

Comment: Thank you nanash1 , this is exactly what i needed. ZIP file attached to this discussion contains all informaton necessary to program and verify PAL IC.

Comment: Please post this as an answer starcat

Answer (score 1):

[Link](https://e2e.ti.com/support/logic-group/logic/f/logic-forum/1279055/pal16r4a-2m-programming-tool-enquiry/4850802#4850802) provided by nanash1 contains PAL programming documentation. Thank you!